# Posting an attachment to Rest api with Jira 6.4.3

Tags: c#, rest, post, jira

I'm trying to add an attachment to the Jira REST api (version 6.4.3). 
[Jira 6.4.3 Documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.4.3/#d2e1654)

The problem here is that after some errors i managed to get the response code HTTP/1.1 OK, but there is not data as stated in the jira api and the attachment is not posted.

Here is the full tcp stream:

```
POST /rest/api/2/issue/SANDBOX-106/attachments HTTP/1.1
X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="3555f78b-ebcc-406a-ab5a-8bf9009d7254"
Host: ******
Cookie:*****
Content-Length: 236
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

--3555f78b-ebcc-406a-ab5a-8bf9009d7254
Content-Disposition: file; filename=huowzsqn.hpi

.........   
..
.................. !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abc
--3555f78b-ebcc-406a-ab5a-8bf9009d7254--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-AREQUESTID: 650x4885x1
X-ASESSIONID: 9sodh7
X-ASEN: SEN-4692241
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: ****
X-AUSERNAME: ****
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2016 09:50:39 GMT

2
[]
0
```

The method for posting to the jira api:

```
protected async Task<CQ> preformRequest(string path, FileParamter file, Dictionary<int, Exception> exceptions = null, Dictionary<String, String> headers = null, string dispositionType = "file")
        {
            if (!checkUrl(path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid url.");
            }

            MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            this.addHeaders(headers);

            ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file.File);

            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(dispositionType)
            {
                FileName = file.FileName

            };

            multiPartContent.Add(fileContent);

            var task = Client.PostAsync(path, multiPartContent)
               .ContinueWith(tsk =>
               {
                   HttpStatusCode code = tsk.Result.StatusCode;

                   if (!this.isStatusCodeSuccess(code))
                   {
                       this.handleStatusCodes(code, exceptions);
                   }

                   return tsk.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               });


            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CQ.Create(task.Unwrap().Result));
        }
```

The FileParamter class:

```
public class FileParamter
    {
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public FileParamter(byte[] file) : this(file, null) { }

        public FileParamter(byte[] file, string fileName)
        {
            this.File = file;
            this.FileName = fileName;
        }

        public FileParamter()
        {

        }
    }
```

The test class for generating a random file:

```
public FileParamter createIssueAttachment()
        {
            string filePath =
                System.IO.Path.Combine(
                    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                    System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName());

            //filePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, "txt");

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                {
                    for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        fs.WriteByte(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filePath);

            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            FileParamter fileParamter = new FileParamter
            {
                File =  file, 
                FileName = info.Name 
            };

            this.deleteFile(filePath);

            return fileParamter; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else come over this problem, the problem was with the content disposition in the file header.

It was:

```
Content-Disposition: file; filename=huowzsqn.hpi
```

And should be:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=huowzsqn.hpi; name=file
```

The working method:

```
protected async Task<CQ> preformRequest(string path, FileParamter file, Dictionary<int, Exception> exceptions = null, Dictionary<String, String> headers = null, string dispositionType = "file")
        {
            if (!checkUrl(path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid url.");
            }

            MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            this.addHeaders(headers);

            ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file.File);

            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(dispositionType)
            {
                FileName = file.FileName,
                Name = dispositionType,
                DispositionType = "form-data"
            };

            multiPartContent.Add(fileContent);

            var task = Client.PostAsync(path, multiPartContent)
               .ContinueWith(tsk =>
               {
                   HttpStatusCode code = tsk.Result.StatusCode;

                   if (!this.isStatusCodeSuccess(code))
                   {
                       this.handleStatusCodes(code, exceptions);
                   }

                   return tsk.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               });


            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CQ.Create(task.Unwrap().Result));
        }
```